# How to run ssh without needing as password?

Tags: pi-3, audio

Want to send audio from one RPI to another over my network using sox.
therefore need to run ssh without password.
How to do this on a simple way?

Comment: Research private / public keys. This facilitates secure, passwordless login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using ssh-keys.

Run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` on your client (your first RPI) and follow the instructions. Leave the passphrase empty.

Then copy the public key to your second RPI by running: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@secondRPI`

Now you should be able to login without any password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The first part is OK (client RPIi I'm getting a public key.)  Now for the second part, "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@secondRPI"  - with scond RPI you mean the IP adress of the second RPI?  Sorry, i'm Newbie.  In fact I copied the .ssh directory from the first RPI into my second RPI but i guess this is not the way to do.

Comment: Yes, take the IP address of your second RPI! Copying your .ssh folder is not a good idea, and won't work. So would suggest to remove the .ssh folder on your second py `rm -r .ssh`. And then run `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@IP-address-of-your-second-pi` on your first by.